# Variant of minimum weight perfect matching problem with Hungarian algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matching-theory

Given a complete bipartite graph $G=\{A+B,W\}$ with the number of vertices $|A|<|B|$, suppose I am looking for a subset $B'\subset B$ with $|B'|=|A|$ such that the minimum weight perfect matching between the vertices $a_i\in A$ and $b_i\in B'$ has the minimum weight among all such possible $B'$s. The straightforward way to solve it would be to enumerate all possible $B'$ and then solve each case by Hungarian algorithm. Is there any better algorithm to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with one call to the Hungarian algorithm on an auxiliary complete bipartite graph.  Introduce $|B|-|A|$ new vertices on the $A$ side so that the left and right node sets have the same cardinality $|B|$.  For the new nodes, let all the edge weights be an arbitrary constant (say, $0$). The nodes in $B$ that get matched to the original nodes yield your desired $B’$.

Comment: I think the weights to those $|B|-|A|$ vertices can be arbitrarily assigned to the same value, not necessarily a smaller number.

Comment: @FellowInstituteOfMathophile Yes, I think you were looking at my first answer rather than my edited version.  Choosing $0$ has the nice property that the objective value is preserved.